# Get server url in Rails model without using request object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the value equivalent to `request.host` without using the `request` object? I want to get the current url in the model without having to pass the request object from controller.

Comment: The underlying question is: why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The Model is not "aware" of the any of the request details unless the Controller informs it of thus.

The http request/response objects used in Rails are provided via Rack, which ActionController inherits from Metal, a Rack interface.

Models, in their most basic terms, are just plain Ruby Objects which inherit some db connectivity and validations functionality from ActiveRecord.

If you provide more detail into your implementation, there is probably a well established work around.